# Way to install PDFlib text extraction tool

Tags: python, pdf, text-extraction

I downloaded the PDFlib tar file from the site. I cant get the way to install it on ubuntu and configure it to python. I am new to using ubuntu. Can anyone tell me the way to install PDFlib?
I downloaded the tar file from this link

http://www.pdflib.com/download/tet/

Comment: It should be posted on and askubuntu.com. Also read this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-to-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file

Comment: Hi! I know this is ages ago for you, but did you have any luck? I am having a lot of difficulty installing PDFLib TET on python myself.

Answer (score 1):

From the manual of [PDFlib TET](https://www.pdflib.com/fileadmin/pdflib/pdf/manuals/TET-5.3-manual.pdf):

> Installing the TET edition for Python:
> The Python extension mechanism works by loading shared libraries at runtime. For the TET binding to work, the Python interpreter must have access to the TET Python wrapper which will be searched in the directories listed in the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable.

The TET Python wrapper is the `tetlib_py.so` which you find in the tarball you downloaded (choose the correct one for your version of Python). In addition to the `tetlib_py.so` the files `PDFLib/TET.py` and `PDFlib/__init__.py` must be available in the same directory.

Comment: Can you please elaborate what you mean? Perhaps, an example might be a great help.

Comment: @rjs Thank you for your contribution! Please note however that copying information from external sources without attribution is considered plagiarism and not welcome on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

python comes with own package manager called pip. Try

> pip install pypdflib

in the command line.

Another approach is to use ubuntu package manager - apt-get, aptitude, synaptic, etc...
Check if the package in ubuntu repositories:

> apt-cache search python pdflib

and if such entry found, issue:

> apt-get install "package name here"

Comment: apt-get and apt-cache is not working for this package. and i think pypdflib is different from the pdflib package.

Comment: is there any other way? i have bin file in the package which has tet file in it..can it be installed?

Comment: PDFlib TET is [commercial product](https://www.pdflib.com/buy/online-shop/pdflib-tet/) and is not in any way related to the `pypdflib` package on Pypi and a package with the name `pdflib` does not appear in the current Ubuntu Package Database.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open a Terminal and switch to an arbitrary directory where you want to put the TET library.
2. Download [PDFlib TET](https://www.pdflib.com/download/tet/) for your Linux (here: Intel 64-bit) in the scriping language version (Perl, PHP, Python, Ruby).

   ```
   wget -q https://www.pdflib.com/binaries/TET/530/TET-5.3p6-Linux-x64-Perl-PHP-Python-Ruby.tar.gz
   ```
3. Extract the archive and rename the base directory to `TET-5.3p6`.

   ```
   tar xzf TET-5.3p6-Linux-x64-Perl-PHP-Python-Ruby.tar.gz
   mv TET-5.3p6-Linux-x64-Perl-PHP-Python-Ruby TET-5.3p6
   ```
4. Create the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable.*

   ```
   export PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:$PWD/TET-5.3p6/bind/python"
   ```
5. Start Python and create a document handle.

   ```
   $ python3
   Python 3.9.2 (default, Feb 28 2021, 17:03:44) 
   [GCC 10.2.1 20210110] on linux
   Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
   >>> from PDFlib.TET import *
   >>> tet = TET()
   >>> handle = tet.open_document('input.pdf', '')
   ```
6. To get a list of the available methods

   ```
   >>> help(TET)
   ```

For further information see the [TET manual](https://www.pdflib.com/fileadmin/pdflib/pdf/manuals/TET-5.3-manual.pdf).

<sub>* You might want to add this to your `.bashrc` so it will available in new shells</sub>